# Express-Session session data not returning session-data in Chrome and Edge

Tags: express, express-session

My express-session is only working on Firefox, Chrome and Edge are sending the session id but only the cookie details are retrieved. I have tried all available online remedies to this with no success.

My Session settings:

```
app.use(helmet());

app.set("trust proxy", 1); // trust first proxy
  //initialize session management
  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({client:redisClient}),
      saveUninitialized:false,
      secret:process.env.USER_SESSION_SECRET,
      resave:true,
      unset:'destroy',
      cookie:{
   
          path:"/",
          maxAge:1000*60*60,
          httpOnly:true,
          secure:process.env.NODE_ENV==="production"?true:false,
        
      },
  
       
    }))
```

Setting the session data object after login

```
req.session.auth=dataObject;
```

Session data from Edge and Chrome

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2022-06-04T08:07:57.827Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
```

Mozilla session data

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2022-06-04T08:08:30.526Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  auth: {
    identification_number: null,
    id: 4,
    total_spent: 0,
    account_type: 'Copper',
    status: 'Active',
    isMerchant: false,
    role: 'Client',
    isAdmin: false,
    location: null,
    rank: 'Admin',
    session_expires: '2022-06-04T08:08:30.049Z',
    logo: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dfnuodjiw/image/upload/v1650034813/logos/construction_woman_bmlnma.jpg'
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably Edge and Chrome consider the session cookie a third-party cookie, because frontend and backend run on different top-level domains (`.frontend.com` vs `.backend.com`). This effectively gives a fresh session with every request.

Comment: thank you for this, how would i rectify that